# Internal call inside a function object, (Boost::apply_visitor specific)

Tags: boost, set, variant, evaluator

I am currently writing a set expression evaluator which generates set< T > and set< set< T > >, the code below is to display the result of the expression.

```
class string_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<string>
{
public:
    string operator()(bool value) const
    {
        return "{}";
    }

    string operator()(set<T> value) const
    {
        set<T>::const_iterator it = value.begin();
        string output = "{";

        if(!value.empty())
        {
            output += *it; // Return an empty set if necessary.
            ++it;
        }

        for(; it != value.end(); ++it)
        {
            output += " " + *it;
        }
        output += "}";

        return output;
    }

    string operator()(set<set<T> > value) const
    {
        set<set<T> >::const_iterator it = value.begin();
        string output = "{";

        if(!value.empty())
        {
            output += boost::apply_visitor(string_visitor(), *it); // Return an empty set if necessary.
            ++it;
        }

        for(; it != value.end(); ++it)
        {
            output += " " + boost::apply_visitor(string_visitor(), *it);
        }
        output += "}";

        return output;
    }
};
```

The problem I am experiencing is happening when I try to evaluate sets of sets using the set code, obviously I am using this as it is good practice but the compiler doesn't appear to like the syntax I am using to construct the call.

```
output += boost::apply_visitor(string_visitor(), *it);
```

There are two lines like that, they produce the trace..

> e:\documents\level 3\advanced software engineering\coursework\coursework\boost\variant\detail\apply_visitor_unary.hpp(76) : error C2039: 'apply_visitor' : is not a member of 'std::set<_Kty>'
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            _Kty=std::string
>   1>        ]
>   1>        e:\documents\level 3\advanced software engineering\coursework\coursework\context.h(96) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> boost::apply_visitor::ExpressionTree::string_visitor,const std::set<_Kty>>(const Visitor &,Visitable &)' being compiled
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            _Elem=char,
>   1>            _Traits=std::char_traits,
>   1>            _Ax=std::allocator,
>   1>            T=std::string,
>   1>            _Kty=std::string,
>   1>            Visitor=Context::ExpressionTree::string_visitor,
>   1>            Visitable=const std::set
>   1>        ]
>   1>        e:\documents\level 3\advanced software engineering\coursework\coursework\context.h(90) : while compiling class template member function 'std::string Context::ExpressionTree::string_visitor::operator ()(std::set<_Kty>) const'
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            T=std::string,
>   1>            _Kty=std::set
>   1>        ]
>   1>        e:\documents\level 3\advanced software engineering\coursework\coursework\context.cpp(337) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Context::ExpressionTree::string_visitor' being compiled
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            T=std::string
>   1>        ]

Does anyone have any idea of how to phrase that sort of call?

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score -1):

Managed to fix the problem by simply type-casting the variable back to the type of variant I defined. so in my case it was solved by:

```
output += boost::apply_visitor(string_visitor(), (Context<T>::ExpressionTree::stackType) *it);
```

Hope that helps out others!

Comment: Lathford: A better approach would be to make your parameters `const&` (as in `set<T> const& value`), which would (a) avoid the nasty unsafe cast, (b) avoid unnecessary copies in case `set` is expensive to copy, and (c) prevent you from accidentally modifying the expression tree, which is probably reasonable for pretty-printing.